# How can I get my chat to accept more than one client?

Tags: java, sockets, chat, serversocket

I am trying to create a multi-client to server chat. This works fine while chatting one-to-one, but when I try to run another client and connect it, it does not go through/connects. Am I missing something on the threads? I only added the Server and Client classes without the imports, there is the main class that asks the user if it wants to be a server or client(join) and asks for the port...

```
    public Server(int port, String name) {
        frame = new JFrame("Messenger");
        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        hostport = port; 
        userText = new JTextField(); //Input text field
        userText.setEditable(false); //Can't write until connected with someone
        userText.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                        sendMessage(event.getActionCommand(), name);
                        userText.setText("");
                    }
                    
                }
            );
        JButton jbutton = new JButton("Browse File");
        JPanel messagePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        jbutton.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                        JFileChooser file = new JFileChooser();
                        file.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
                        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("*.Images", "jpg","gif","png");
                        file.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
                        int result = file.showSaveDialog(null);
                         if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                              File selectedFile = file.getSelectedFile();
                              String path = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
                              userText.setText(path);
                          }
                          else if(result == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION){
                              System.out.println("No File Select");
                          }
                        }
                }
          );
                
                messagePanel.add(userText, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                messagePanel.add(jbutton, BorderLayout.EAST);
                chatWindow = new JTextArea();
                add(new JScrollPane(chatWindow));
                chatWindow.setSize(400, 300);
                frame.add(chatWindow, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.add(messagePanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.setVisible(true);
    
                t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                     @Override
                        public void run(){
                            startRunning(name);
                        }
                    });
                 
                }
    
    
    //set up and run de server 
    public void startRunning(String servName) {
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(hostport);
            while(true) {
                try {
                    waitForConnection(servName);
                    setupStreams();
                    whileChatting();    
                }catch(EOFException eofException) {
                    showMessage("\n Connection Ended");
                }finally {
                    close();
                }
            }
            
        }catch(IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace(); //prints error
        }
    }
    //wait for connection
    private void waitForConnection(String servName) throws IOException{
        showMessage("Waiting for someone to connect");
        socket = server.accept();
        showMessage("\nNow connected to: " + socket.getInetAddress() + servName);
    }
    //get stream to send and receive data 
    private void setupStreams() throws IOException{
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        output.flush();
        input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        showMessage("\n Streams Are now Set up \n");
    }
    
    //during the chat conversation
    private void whileChatting() throws IOException{
        String message = "You are now connected ";
        showMessage(message);
        ableToType(true);
        do {
            try {
                message = (String) input.readObject();
                showMessage("\n" + message);
            }catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException) {
                showMessage("\n Error on input \n");
            }
            
        }while(!message.equals("CLIENT - END"));
    }
    
    //Close streams and sockets in java after done chatting
    private void close() {
        showMessage("\n Closing connections... \n");
        ableToType(false);
        try {
            output.close(); //stream close
            input.close(); //stream close 
            socket.close(); //connection close
            
        }catch(IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace(); //prints error
        }
    }
    
    //sends message to the client 
    private void sendMessage(String message, String name) {
        try {
            output.writeObject(name + ": " + message);
            output.flush(); //cleans input stream, flush all the extra bites 
            showMessage("\n " + name + ": " + message);
        }catch(IOException ioException) {
            chatWindow.append("\n Error ");
        }
    }
    
    //updates chat window (displays messages)
    private void showMessage(final String text) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( //allows thread that updates parts of the GUI
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        chatWindow.append(text);
                    }
                }
            );
        
    }
    
    //lets the user type text into their box 
    private void ableToType(final boolean tof) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( //allows thread that updates parts of the GUI
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        userText.setEditable(tof);
                    }
                }
            );
    }
```

```
    public Client(String IPAdress, int port, String name){
        frame = new JFrame("Client");
        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        
        serverIP = IPAdress;
        HostPort = port;
        userText = new JTextField(); //Input text field
        userText.setEditable(false); //Can't write until connected with someone
        userText.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                        sendData(event.getActionCommand(), name);
                        userText.setText("");
                    }
                }
            );
        JButton jbutton = new JButton("Browse File");
        JPanel messagePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        jbutton.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                        JFileChooser file = new JFileChooser();
                        file.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
                        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("*.Images", "jpg","gif","png");
                        file.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
                        int result = file.showSaveDialog(null);
                         if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                              File selectedFile = file.getSelectedFile();
                              String path = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
                              userText.setText(path);
                          }
                          else if(result == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION){
                              System.out.println("No File Select");
                          }
                        }
                }
          );
        
        //add JTextField to CENTER and button to EAST
        messagePanel.add(userText, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        messagePanel.add(jbutton, BorderLayout.EAST);
        chatWindow = new JTextArea();
        add(new JScrollPane(chatWindow));
        chatWindow.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.add(chatWindow, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(messagePanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run(){
                startRunnable();
            }
        });
     
    }

    //connect to server 
    public void startRunnable() {
        try {
            while(true) {
        try {
            connectToServer();
            setupStreams();
            whileChatting();

        }catch(EOFException eofException) {
            showMessage("\n Connection Ended");
        }finally {
            close();
        }
            }
        }catch(IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace(); //prints error
        }
    }
 //connection to server 
    private void connectToServer() throws IOException{
        showMessage("\n Attempting connection");
        connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP),HostPort);
        showMessage("\nNow connected to " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
    }
    
    
    //get stream to send and receive data 
        private void setupStreams() throws IOException{
            try {
            output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            output.flush();
            input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            showMessage("llegue?");
            showMessage("\n Streams Are now Set up \n");
            }catch(IOException ioException) {
                chatWindow.append("\n Error seting up stream");
            }
        }
        
        //during the chat conversation
        private void whileChatting() throws IOException{
            ableToType(true);
            do {
                try {
                    message = (String) input.readObject();
                    showMessage("\n" + message);
                }catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException) {
                    showMessage("\n Error on input \n");
                }
                
            }while(!message.equals("SERVER - END"));
        }

        //Close streams and sockets in java after done chatting
        private void close() {
            showMessage("\n Closing connections... \n");
            ableToType(false);
            try {
                output.close(); //stream close
                input.close(); //stream close 
                connection.close(); //connection close
                
                
            }catch(IOException ioException) {
                ioException.printStackTrace(); //prints error
            }
        }
        
        //sends message to the client 
        private void sendData(String message, String name) {
            try {
                output.writeObject(name + ": "+message);
                output.flush(); //cleans input stream, flush all the extra bites 
                showMessage("\n" + name + ": "+ message);
            }catch(IOException ioException) {
                chatWindow.append("\n Error ");
            }
        }
        
        //updates chat window (displays messages)
        private void showMessage(final String M) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater( //allows thread that updates parts of the GUI
                    new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            chatWindow.append(M);
                        }
                    }
                );
            
        }
        
        //lets the user type text into their box 
        private void ableToType(final boolean tof) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater( //allows thread that updates parts of the GUI
                    new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            userText.setEditable(tof);
                        }
                    }
                );
        }
        
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are only using `server.accept()` when your current client disconnects.

In order to receive more connections, you need to actively listen for new connections.
So in this case, you would need a thread that is actively listening and accepting new connections, and another thread that checks if the sockets you already have have any data.

Maybe it would be better to use UDP in this case, since you could just open a port for everyone and listen there, and have every client identify itself on the data it sends, that way you would not need to listen to a port connection and also to every client at the same time.